# Query not exposed attributes from PostGIS

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, qgis, osm2pgsql

I loaded an osm-file into PostGIS by using osm2pgsql. Now, I would like to query features with specific attributes. For example: "highway is not null" with "maxspeed is not null". 
PGadmin returns: "ERROR:  column "maxspeed" does not exist"

From overpass-turbo I know, my area of interest provides such characteristics.
So should be present.

```
select * from planet_osm_line
where highway is not null and maxspeed is not null
```

I expect a query result with a additional attribute column of "maxspeed", but 
PGadmin returns: "ERROR:  column "maxspeed" does not exist"

Comment: check for exact column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a [similar question at gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/135715/23837). Quoting the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/135747/23837):

> The default.style file
>   https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/default.style
>   does not pick maxspeed into its own column. Edit default.style or use
>   the --hstore option for writing all the tags into hstore.